# Blender 3.0: Toggle visibility of all items in a collection?

Tags: interface, collections

Is there a way to make sure that all items in a collection, and its sub-collections, are visible for render and/or viewport editing? Currently the only way I know to do this is to expand the collection, and its subcollections, and visually inspect each item.

Unfortunately, it's not unusual for me to render a complicated scene only to realize that I'd forgotten to unhide one or more items that I'd hidden during the editing process. At the very least, it would be useful if I could right-click a collection and toggle the visibility of every associated item. Any such method? Thanks.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thank you! By the way, I want to mark your answer as the right answer, but I see no option here, just the up arrow. As I recall, on some occasions I've seen an option for marking a response as the right answer, but not this time? Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while toggling the property on the outermost collection. That will recursively apply the change to all nested collections.